# Word variable when assigned to int type variable,it has ffff in front of it...why?

Tags: c++

```
short ab = 0x8400;
WORD val = ab;
INT val1 = ab;
CString strMsg = _T("");
strMsg.Format(_T("value of val1 = %x"), ab);
AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
```

then `ab` has `0xffff8400`
why?
from where this `0xffff` come from ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

Comment: Use unsigned if you don't want the top bit to be a sign bit.

Comment: "only 0x8400 having 00 in front and after this value" - "this value" - refers to *which value* ? `devId` or `a` ?

Comment: It shouldn't be. The value of `devId` is `0x8400`, or `33792` in decimal. Assuming `int` is 32 bits, that value can be represented as an `int`, so the conversion from `WORD` to `int` should result in the value `33792` being stored. If it's displayed as an 8-digit hexadecimal value, it should be `0x00008400`. Can you show us a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem? How exactly are you examining the value of `a`? Also, how is this related to the MIcrosoft Foundation Class library?

Comment: @Quentin: No sign extension should be happening here.

Comment: What type, exactly, is `WORD`?

Comment: If you print `a` it is still 0x8400

Comment: Try it yourself. -31744. http://ideone.com/y8tiq5

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I assumed that `WORD` is a 16-bit unsigned type. And, as it turns out, it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, you know what, I just did the same and you're right. Somehow the OP's "WORD" type is behaving as if it's signed, or more likely, he is not showing us the actual code.

Comment: http://ideone.com/EN9TPA  <-- if WORD is unsigned

Comment: The results can't be reproduced in a small, self-contained example. I am going to vote to close if OP can't fix the question...

Comment: I've removed the "c" tag, since the code appears to be C++, not C. I've also removed the "mfc" tag since, as far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with the MIcrosoft Foundation Class library library.

Comment: The edit improves the question, but the code is still incomplete. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2):

```
short ab = 0x8400;
```

Assuming `short` is 16 bits, the value `0x8400` (decimal 33792) cannot be represented as a `short`, so you have an overflow. The value stored in `ab` is, strictly speaking, implementation-defined. In practice, the actual value stored is likely to be 33792 - 2<sup>16</sup>, or `-31744`.

```
WORD val = ab;
```

Assuming `WORD` is a typedef for `unsigned short` (as it is on Windows), this converts the value of `ab`, `-31744`, from `short` to `unsigned short`. The result is `33792`, or `0x8400`.  But this is irrelevant, since you never use the value of `val`.

```
INT val1 = ab;
```

I'll assume `INT` is a typedef for `int`.  I don't know why you'd use such a typedef.  If `INT` is always the same type as `int`, there's no point in using `INT` rather than `int`. If `INT` can possibly be anything other than `int`, then it's a horribly misleading name.

Anyway, this simply converts the value of `ab` from `short` to `int`. Since that value, `-31744`, is within the range of `int`, the conversion preserves the value, so `ab == -31744`.

```
strMsg.Format(_T("value of val1 = %x"), ab);
```

Assuming that `strMsg.Format` is similar to `printf`, the `%x` format specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. `ab` is of type `int` (well, `INT`, but we're assuming it's the same). This will probably treat the contents of the `int` object `ab` *as if* it were of type `unsigned int`. The result `0xffff8400` is what I'd expect if `int` is 32 bits and represented using two's-complement. But if you want to see the actual value of `ab`, use the correct format specifier, `%d`.

The following was the answer to the original version of your question. Your edit changed the code and the value of the variable you're examining; originally the code in the question was inconsistent with the results you reported.

<strike>Quick summary: `a` *doesn't have the value `0xffff8400`; you're probably just displaying it incorrectly.</strike>

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `WORD` is a 16-bit unsigned type, a typedef for `unsigned short`.

```
WORD devId = 0x8400;
```

This sets `devId` to `0x8400`, or `33792` in decimal. This is within the range of values representable in a `WORD` (0 to 65535), so there's no problem so far.

```
int a = devId;
```

Assuming that `int` is 32 bits, the value `33792` is implicitly converted from `WORD` to `int`. Since it's well within the range of value for `int`, the conversion keeps the same value, so `a` will be equal to `33792`, or `0x8400`.

If you examine `a` as a 32-bit quantity, using hexadecimal, it should look like `0x00008400`.

(If `int` is 16 bits, then the conversion of `33792` from `WORD` to `int` will, strictly speaking, yield an implementation-defined result. It's very likely that that result will be `-31744`. When viewed *as an unsigned 16-bit quantity*, it should look like `0x8400`. But it's unlikely you're using a system with 16-bit `int`. If you are, please update your question to make that clear.)

So why are you seeing the incorrect value `0xffff8400`? I have no idea. I can only guess that the code you use to print the value of `a` is incorrect -- or that the code that defines and initializes `a` isn't what you've shown us.

If you update your question to show us how you're printing `0xffff8400`, preferably as part of a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), we can help. Otherwise all I can say is that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: i have modified the question ,mentioned an example,sorry for inconvenience because of my previous example

Comment: thanks a lot for your clear and helpful explanation,i vil try the same from my side next time ,,